# How can I get share count using the new Twitter Search APIs?

Tags: twitter, social-networking, twitter-search

I wonder if it's still possible to use the Search API on client side using an AJAX call, C# would be fine too, but so far I'm finding a lot of talk about this but no code sample or any good instructions how this can be done,

[Some sites like these are doing it](http://marketingland.com/twitter-share-numbers-159379) but obviously this got way more complicated to do than before

I don't see any practice examples on https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As you've discovered, Twitter has turned off the sharecount API - see https://twittercommunity.com/t/a-new-design-for-tweet-and-follow-buttons/52791/5 and https://blog.twitter.com/developer/en_us/a/2015/hard-decisions-for-a-sustainable-platform.html

There are some alternatives like https://opensharecount.com/

That works by continually searching the Twitter API and counting up all the shares that it sees.

Comment: Yes that's my point, that is what I'm trying to do - I want to search by shared URL and keep the counts in my database... but not sure how to use the APIs - the Twitter developer page does not seems to have any practical examples...